# Why unique index AND unique constraint (multi columns)?

Tags: oracle, constraints, unique-constraint

So a table I am looking at has a unique constraint AND a unique index over multiple columns, and the exact same columns for both.

Is there a use for this or is the unique constraint redundant?

Comment: A unique constraint has to be backed up by an index; though that doesn't *have* to be unique itself. It's normal to have both. They usually have the same name, but again that isn't always the case. And you can of course have a unique index without an explicit unique constraint. But the constraint makes it clear (to Oracle and developers) that this is for integrity, not just performance. Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: Agree with Alex, but I'll add that if something in there was to be regarded as redundant, I'd pick the uniqueness of the index. I'd rather have a unique constraint and a non-unique index than no constraint and a unique index.

Comment: According to MSDN article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(v=sql.80).aspx There's no practical difference between a unique constraint and a unique index other than the fact that the unique constraint is also listed as a constraint object in the database. Since a unique constraint can't be disabled, having the status of a constraint doesn't give the unique constraint any additional behavior beyond a unique index. However, there are several index creation options that aren't available to the ALTER TABLE command that creates a unique constraint. Refer article

Comment: @Gopidoss - a unique constraint can be disabled (which drops the index), and can also be deferrable, a unique index can't. For Oracle anyway, which the question is about; no idea about SQL Server...

Comment: Also a foreign key can refer to a unique key (constraint); the constraint has to exist, just having a unique index isn't enough. So there are practical differences.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the existence of unique constraints *and* unique indexes does look redundant at first.  It seems like a violation of Don't Repeat Yourself,  allowing for confusing differences.  But there are at least two reasons both exist - management features and allowing existing duplicates.

**Management Features**

In theory, a logical constraint can be created without worrying about the implementation.  The constraint specifies what must be true, along with some options such as deferring the constraint until a commit.

In practice, constraints have such a large performance and storage penalty that the implementation must be considered.  An index is required or else a single insert would require O(n) time instead of O(log(n)).  Those indexes can take up a huge amount of space; someone might want to specify where it's stored, how it's compressed, etc.

Most of the time those features aren't important and using all the index defaults is fine.  But sometimes storage and performance are critical and people will want to tweak the index without caring about the constraint.

**Allow Existing Duplicates**

There is at least one case where a unique constraint does not have a unique index.  It's possible to allow existing duplicate valuess but prevent any future duplicates by setting the constraint to `NOVALIDATE` and using a non-unique index.

```
--Create table and insert duplicate values.
create table test1(a number);

insert into test1 values(1);
insert into test1 values(1);
commit;

--Add a non-validated unique constraint, with a non-unique index.
alter table test1
add constraint test1_uq unique(a)
using index (create /* Not unique!*/ index test1_uq on test1(a)) novalidate;

--Now multiple inserts raise: ORA-00001: unique constraint (JHELLER.TEST1_UQ) violated
insert into test1 values(2);
insert into test1 values(2);
```

The physical index must allow duplicates, but the logical constraint knows to not allow any more duplicates.  Although this is a rare feature and I'm not sure if I've ever seen it in production code.

Comment: Adding a unique constraint as deferrable creates a non-unique index automatically as well.